# XCode 4: Statically analyzing header files

Tags: xcode, clang

I have a C++ project (GNU style, with Makefile) and I would like to use XCode as my IDE as I would like to use the Clang functionality of auto-completion and detecting issues live.

To do so, I created a New Project -> Command Line Tool, and then just imported all my files. If I go ahead and edit a .cpp file, XCode detects live issues (gives me an error if I write bogus code). However, the same does not work for my .h files. Interestingly enough, it seems to work if I #include those header files in one of my .cpp files.

How can I resolve this, without having to include the header files from the source files?
Also, I am not sure if this way of creating a project (Command Line Tool) is correct. I really only want to use XCode for auto-completion and issue detection, I do not want to build it through XCode (running "make" is good enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a "translation" file for your project. This would basically be a .c, .cpp, .m, etc file which includes the headers you want indexed.

The underlying problem is that Xcode really does not have enough context to index the world (or any file it navigates to). A singular index representation for a header is not correct. It may seem silly, but when you think about it, it makes sense because every target has different build settings and the singular translation would not apply those correctly.

Xcode 4.0 did it the way you want (basically, everything was indexed based on the build settings of the current project), but that was buggy and quite unusable in nontrivial projects and especially projects that had different build settings. For example: It would apply the prefix header of the wrong project, or not know how to properly construct the include graph so it would just throw errors all over the header (in some cases).

One beneficial side effect to this is that your translation file can be used to do a quick informal check of the files you include before really kicking off the full build. I actually have translation files in libraries for this purpose (and to verify dependencies/includes are correct).

If you really dislike the translation file, you can jump back to Xcode 4.0 or try MacVim's clang_complete.